# Finding a basis for unification of two subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem :

$U,W \subseteq R^4$

Base of $W = \{w1 = (1,2,2,-2), w2 = (0,1,2,-1)\}$

Base of $U = \{u1 = (1,1,0,-1),u2 = (0,1,3,1)\}$

Find a basis for $U \cap W$.

**My solution**

for any $v \in U \cap W$, $v \in W$ and $v \in U$

I need to find $\lambda_1...\lambda_4$ that appiles:

$\lambda_1u1+\lambda_2u2=\lambda_3w1+\lambda_4w2$

Hence (put the vectors as colums),

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0       \\
2 & 1 & -1 & -1       \\
2 & 2 & 0 & -3       \\
-2 & -1 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$

After elementary operations:

EDIT:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0       \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0       \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1      \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$

Therefore :

$\lambda_1=\lambda_3$

$\lambda_2=-\lambda_3$

$\lambda_3=arbitrary$

$\lambda_4=0$

Therefore basis of $U \cap W=Sp\{(1,-1,1,0)\}$

For some reason I don't get the same results as the book.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first 
that the answer you have got is the scalar multiple of your answer not.. If it is not then your answer is wrong because your elementary row operation it is clear that $dim(U \cap W)=1$[ if you haven't done any calculation mistake!!]

Another simple method you can do, just take that matrix & do elementary column operation [don't interchange any column just]. The columns you will get non vanishing atlast. Put the corresponding original basis as the basis of $V \cup W$ [explain why??]. You know basis of $U$ & $W$. rest is upto you.

Comment: You'r right, I calculated it wrong, thanks:)

Comment: I re-calculated but the solution is still not like the one shown in the book, can you please take a look?